# Yet another ClassNotFoundException + Google Play Services plea

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, google-play-services

I've probably just not found the right link, but I am struggling here.

First off, as the header says, I am experiencing a ClassNotFoundException error when attempting to use AppStateClient.connect to use the "game" cloud storage service.  I (to my knowledge) have done the account setup and manifest modifications properly.

I have put the google-play-services.jar as checked in the order/export build path area, and moved it to the top priority as well.

Debugging this on my Nexus 7 running Paranoid Android 3.65 (=Android 4.2.2), which does have the Google Play Services process running (v3.1.59 (736673-30)).  Environment is ADT Bundle v22.0.1

Stack trace appears as follows:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception ClassNotFoundException))    
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
PathClassLoader(BaseDexClassLoader).findClass(String) line: 65  
PathClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: 501   
PathClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: 461    
e(p).connect() line: not available  
AppStateClient.connect() line: not available    
PGA4DetailFragment.connect() line: 137  
PGA4DetailFragment.onStart() line: 123  
PGA4DetailFragment(Fragment).performStart() line: 1484  
FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(Fragment, int, int, int, boolean) line: 941 
FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(int, int, int, boolean) line: 1088  
BackStackRecord.run() line: 682 
FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions() line: 1444 
FragmentManagerImpl$1.run() line: 429   
Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 725   
FragmentActivity$1(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92   
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5230    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 525  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 799  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 566
```

Please help!  Thank you

Comment: so have you checked google-play-services.jar as exported?

Comment: I did.  See answer below.  I was hoping to avoid having google-play-services as its own distinct floating project, but apparently that's too advanced for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I was using, I didn't do this important step:

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

After doing this, I am able to get further and no longer get ClassNotFoundExceptions

I surmise the JAR file was never making it down after all, because of this.

Now on to other nifty errors